# Linq multiple where clause with if condition

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write Linq with multiple where clause and where clause further contains inline if conditions.

```
List<MeetingVM> students = (
from s in db.Meetings 
where MeetingIsActive == null || s.IsActive == MeetingIsActive 
where MeetingStat == null || MeetingStat == 5 ? (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime) : s.Status== MeetingStat
where StartDate == null || (s.MeetingStartTime >= StartDate && s.MeetingStartTime <= EndDate) 
where s.Status!=4 
orderby s.MeetingStartTime ascending 
select new MeetingVM
{
    MeetingStartTime = s.MeetingStartTime,
    MeetingStopTime = s.MeetingStopTime,
    Alias = s.Alias,
    MeetingSubject = s.MeetingSubject,
    UserId = s.UserId,
    Status=s.Status

}).ToList();
```

This if condition executes (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime) even if MeetingStat==null.

```
where MeetingStat == null || MeetingStat==5 ? (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime) : s.Status== MeetingStat
```

If i remove this..

```
MeetingStat==5 ? (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime) :
```

It works.
But i wanted to write this to check

```
if (MeetingStat==5)
  (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime) 
else 
  s.Status== MeetingStat.
```

What wrong am i doing?

Comment: "not working" is not a condition we could help you with. Please post the error message.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: if condition executes this (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime) even if MeetingStat==null.

Comment: I still don't see an error message.

Comment: I am getting no error instead i am getting unexpected result even if MeetingStat is null this becomes execute (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTi

Comment: At some point it is a good idea to put that Lamba in a function or statement lambda doing good ol' if/else. Cramming everything into one line yields you exactly those kind of problems and suffer readability.

Comment: How to do that can you please help me to do that.

Comment: Do you mean `((MeetingStat==5) && (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime)) || (!(MeetingStat==5) && s.Status== MeetingStat)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's get the code formatted in a way that's not stupidly difficult to read:

```
List<MeetingVM> students = (
    from s in db.Meetings 
    where MeetingIsActive == null || s.IsActive == MeetingIsActive 
    where MeetingStat == null || MeetingStat == 5 ? (DateTime.UtcNow >= s.MeetingStartTime && DateTime.UtcNow <= s.MeetingStopTime) : s.Status== MeetingStat
    where StartDate == null || (s.MeetingStartTime >= StartDate && s.MeetingStartTime <= EndDate) 
    where s.Status!=4 
    orderby s.MeetingStartTime ascending 
    select new MeetingVM
    {
        MeetingStartTime = s.MeetingStartTime,
        MeetingStopTime = s.MeetingStopTime,
        Alias = s.Alias,
        MeetingSubject = s.MeetingSubject,
        UserId = s.UserId,
        Status=s.Status

    }).ToList();
```

That's a little better.

Now, I'm not 100% sure on this, so someone who knows better can feel free to correct me, but according to [C# Operator Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx), the OR ("||") operator has a higher precedence than the conditional ("?:") operator, so this line:

```
where MeetingStat == null || MeetingStat == 5 ? ...
```

is essentially getting evaluated like this:

```
where (MeetingStat == null || MeetingStat == 5) ? ...
```

If `MeetingStat` is equal to true, this would make the expression evaluate the first branch of the ternary operation. Judging from your description in your question, this is not what you want, so I recommend surrounding the ternary operation in parentheses to make your intention clear:

```
where MeetingStat == null || (MeetingStat == 5 ? ... )
```

Comment: Wow. I can't even think parentheses can make such a change. It's working correctly now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `DateTime.UtcNow` Better you store its value in a variable nad then use the same in LINQ as like this:

```
DateTime UtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
// and change the condition like this;
.Where MeetingStat != null && MeetingStat==5 ? (UtcTime >= s.MeetingStartTime && UtcTime <= s.MeetingStopTime) : s.Status== MeetingStat
```

It is happening so because your predicates inside the Where clause was not getting translated to SQL, If you are using like this means your code will works as expected since `UtcTime` is now convertible

Comment: still when MeetingStat is null it executes (UtcTime >= s.MeetingStartTime && UtcTime <= s.MeetingStopTime).

Comment: What you actually want their? if you dont want to execute rest if `MeetingStat = null` means replace `||` with `&&`

Comment: if there is null then it should not check into ||

Comment: Then your condition should be like this : `Where MeetingStat != null &&  ...` see the updates